# What does $\sin(4\theta)$ equal?

Tags: trigonometry

I want to write $\sin(4\theta)$ in terms of $\cos(\theta)$ and $\sin(\theta)$. My work:

\begin{align*}\sin(4\theta) & = 2\sin(2\theta) \cos(2\theta) 
\\ &= 2[(2\sin(\theta) \cos(\theta)(2\cos^2(\theta)-1)] 
\\ &= 2(4\sin(\theta) \cos^3(\theta) - 2\sin(\theta) \cos(\theta)) 
\\ &= 8\sin(\theta) \cos^3(\theta) - 4\sin(\theta) \cos(\theta) 
\end{align*}
This is wrong. Why? The solution manual says it's $\cos(\theta)(4\sin(\theta) - 8\sin^3(\theta))$.

Thanks.

Comment: The first line should be $$\color{red}{\sin(4\theta)} ~= 2\sin(2\theta)\cos(2\theta).$$

Comment: Why do you say it is wrong (assuming you change $4\theta$ to $\sin4\theta?$)

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I have a solution manual that gives a different answer.

Comment: @user2661923 sorry, that's what I meant.

Comment: Consider $\theta=\pi$, Now do you think $4\pi=0$?

Comment: @Rolomoto Keep in mind that since $\sin^2x+\cos^2x=1$, it's possible for different polynomial expressions in $(\sin x,\cos x)$ to indicate the same function. Therefore when you compare a solution from the manual with your own you should also check if they are the same.

Comment: Well, maybe you could tell us all the information. If the book answer is different, then tell us what the book gives you. Help us help you. (What the book gives you will sometimes help us help clarify the question.)

Comment: The book answer is equal to your answer, by taking $$\sin^3x=\sin x(1-\cos^2x)$$

Comment: There are multiple ways to write the same expression.  $4\sin\theta\cos^3\theta - 4\sin^3\theta\cos\theta$ is another.

Comment: the place you first made a choice was in $$ \cos 2 \theta = 2 \cos^2 \theta - 1 = 1 - 2 \sin^2 \theta$$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews How did you come with $\sin^3x=\sin x(1-\cos^2x)$? I mean it works but only after plugging it in do I see that it works.

Comment: $\sin^2 x=1-\cos^2x$ then multiply both sides by $\sin x.$ @Rolomoto

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio Do you mean for example that instead of $\sin^2x+\cos^2x=1$ you could write $\sin^2 x=1-\cos^2x$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those two equations are the same. Using $\cos^2(\theta) = 1 - \sin^2(\theta)$ you get your equation:
$= 4\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta) - 8\sin(\theta)^3\cos(\theta) \\
= 4\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta) - 8\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta) \cdot (1-\cos^2(\theta)) \\
= -4\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta) + 8\sin(\theta)\cos^3(\theta) \\
= 8\sin(\theta)\cos^3(\theta) - 4\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta)$